# How do I get data to table

Tags: python, pandas

I'm just getting started with python
I used that code to get some data

```
for key, value in analysis.items():
    print(key, {k:v for k,v in value.items() if k in "file.txt"})
```

And result is:

```
X:Y {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 4, 'd': 5}
T:Z {'a': 7, 'b': 6, 'c': 3, 'd': 9}
```

But I want to get my result on table in Excel. I tried `pandas.DataFrame.from_dict` but it's not working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. What did you try exactly, and what was the result? Please [edit] to clarify. For more tips, see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Since you are printing the result, you will receive it in the form of the standard output. To get this in a csv file format, try:

```
import csv # this line goes at the top of the file

with open('result.csv', 'w+') as result:
    writer = csv.writer(result)
    for key, value in analysis.items():
        writer.writerow([key, {k:v for k,v in value.items() if k in "file.txt"}])
```

Then open `result.csv` with Excel.

Comment: Sorry. I don't get it. Where can I find "result.csv".

Comment: in the files on your device. the code creates the file for you.